# Get value of option without submit form or input ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a select with options and want to get the value of the option without submitting a form or using button or input.
for example, if I choose USD I want the function return USD,
             for EUR, should return EUR

```js
 <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
      <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
      <option value="RUR">RUR</option>
      <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: can you write a bit more about your goal?

Comment: I want to make a currency calculator and when I change the currency in the input below should show the converted value. that's why i don't need button with submitting form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="RUR">RUR</option>
    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
</select>
```

You can access to the selected value inside `handleChange` like so:

```
handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value); // for ex. will print USD
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function `displayUsd()` then in the onChange event of the select element use
`this.displayUsd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in  `onChange={this.handleChange}`

```
 handleChange = (e) => {
  // e.target.value will USD 
 }
```

or

```
 handleChange: function(event){
     // event.target.value
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using a class here and extending react.

```
constructor() {
    this.state = { value: 'default Value' }
}

this.handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value}); 
}
```